# GRE math problem 1

Tags: functions, gre-exam

If $c$ and $d$ are two integers and $@$ is defined in $a$ and $b$ as $@(a,b)=(a+1)(b+2)$, and $@(c,d)$ equals the product of $3$ and $5$, then what could be the value of $c+d$?

A. $-11$

B. $0$

C. $5$

D. $6$

E. $11

I don't understand the question here. Can $@(a,b)=@(c,d)$?

Comment: I think the assumption is that @$(c,d) = 15$, i.e., $(c+1)(d+2)=15$ where $c$ and $d$ are integers. Can you go from there?

Comment: I think so, is the answer $C$ then?

Comment: Yes, I think it is.

Comment: Actually there are two answers here: $A$ and $C$.

Comment: @user36829 Yeah, see below.

Comment: I assumed in the GRE (which I took as recently as last year), that there was exactly one correct answer to each question. However, perhaps I am misremembering. As @Rustyn notes in his answer below, A is also correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
@(c,d) = (c+1)\cdot (d+2) = 3\cdot 5
$$

So you have, $$c+1 = 3 \text{ and } d+2=5$$ or $$c+1 = -3 \text{ and } d+2 = -5$$

In the first solution, you get $c+d = 2+3 = 5$. 
In the second solution, you get 
$$
c+d = -4 + -7 = -11
$$
So $C,A$ are correct.

Comment: There are additional correct answers not among the choices given. For example, $@(0,13)=(0+1)(13+2)$, which “equals the product of 3 and 5,” so 13 is a possible value of $c+d$.

Comment: Correct, I guess his GRE booklet only lists A,C as correct. (I don't know what's up with that)

Comment: Also, $@(-2,-17)=(-2+1)(-17+2)=-1\cdot -15 = 15$, so another possibility is $-2+-17=-19$....

Comment: Nothing more relaxing than breaking one's head over GRE problems on a Tuesday afternoon. Especially ones that have more than one correct answer and correct answers that aren't even listed as choices. :)